# Sum of product of orthonormal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If $v_1,v_2,...v_n$ are orthonormal vectors in $\in \mathbb R^n$ is there anything special about $v_1v_1^T+v_2v_2^T+...+v_nv_n^T$

Comment: Row vectors or column vectors?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy column vectors. I guess I have found the answer. It looks like Identity matrix

Comment: Orthogonal or orthonormal? Let $V$ be the matrix, then $V v_k = \|v_k\|^2 v_k$.

Comment: @copper.hat they have unit length and orthogonal to each other, so yes they are orthonormal

Comment: Then it is the identity since it agrees with  the identity on a basis.

Comment: @StudyingOptimization Please consider accepting one of the answers if it fits your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

If $V = [v_1 \ldots v_n]$, we have that $V^T V = I$. This means $V^T = V^{-1}$, but $VV^{-1} = I$ so, $VV^T = I$. Expanding the latter, we get your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

If $v_i$ is a column vector then multiply $v_1v_1^T+\dots+v_nv_n^T$ by any vector $x$:
$$
(v_1v_1^T+\dots+v_nv_n^T)x=v_1(v_1^Tx)+\dots+v_n(v_n^Tx)
$$
Since $v_i$ make an orthonormal basis, the $v_i^Tx$ is the coefficient in the decomposition of $x$:
$x=a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n$ implies $v_i^Tx=v_i^T(a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n)=a_iv_i^Tv_i=a_i$. Therefore
$$
(v_1v_1^T+\dots+v_nv_n^T)x=v_1(v_1^Tx)+\dots+v_n(v_n^Tx)=x
$$
which implies that $v_1v_1^T+\dots+v_nv_n^T$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

We have $v_j v_j^T=||v_j||^2=1$ for all $j=1,2,...,n.$ Hence $v_1v_1^T+v_2v_2^T+...+v_nv_n^T=n$.

Comment: I believe the vectors are column vectors so the terms are matrices, not scalars.

Comment: Yes, it is an identity matrix